# How to get the content in a div

Tags: php, html, dom

My question was asked before but the answers didn't work for me.

I want to get the content of a div, this is my whole code and what I get:
the lib htmlxml is intalled.

```
<div id="divTest">test 123 </div>
<?php
$xml = new DOMDocument();
$xml->loadHtml('<div id="divTest">test 123 </div>');
$xpath = new DOMXPath($xml);
$html = '';
foreach ($xpath->query('//div[@id="main"]/node()') as $node)
{
$html .= $xml->saveHTML($node);
}
var_dump($html);
?>
```

I get empty string!!!
This is my output :

```
test 123
string(0) ""
```

Comment: Maybe because `id="main"` does not match `id="divTest"`?

Comment: Oooow man, I copied it and forgot to change the div name, it works , thank you

Comment: @JeroenNoten I can accept and upvote your answer if you put it